# MongoDB copy database excluding some collections

Tags: database, mongodb

How can I copy a database ignoring some collections (like `--excludeCollection` in `mongodump`)? I am currently using the `copydb` command and MongoDB 3.6. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 4.2 has [removed Support for the copydb and clone Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-copydb-and-clone-commands):

> Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB removes the deprecated copydb command and clone command.
>
> The corresponding mongo shell helpers db.copyDatabase() and db.cloneDatabase() can only be run when connected to MongoDB 4.0 or earlier.
>
> As an alternative, users can use mongodump and mongorestore or write a script using the drivers.

In light of this, it's best to not indulge on using this command anymore.

To answer your question, `copydb` does not provide a way to selectively copy parts of a database. You would need to use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kevinadi. I have in mind that the copydb has benn deprecated on 4.2, but here we can't upgrade from the 3.6 :(